# How can I hide a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, show-hide

I have created a simple UI in IB, this consists of a `UINavigationBar` and a `UIBarButtonItem` that I dragged and dropped on the right hand side.

I am trying to set this button to be hidden a certain times but I am having some problems.

So far I have tried using:

```
self.NavigationItem.rightBarButton = nil;
```

...which didn't work for me. I have also tried creating and `IBOutlet` and linking it to the button however I'm having problems with this too. I think it should be pretty simple and maybe I'm over-complicating it, but at this point I'm pretty stumped!

Please can someone help me out?

Comment: Make sure your NavigationItem outlet is set.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`UINavigationItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html) doesnt have a `rightBarButton` property.  Try [`rightBarButtonItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/rightBarButtonItem) instead (or `[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];`):

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
// Or
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
// Or
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reset the buttons

```
   -(void)setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated
```

More info here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIToolbar/setItems%3aanimated%3a

You can get the current items using the items property, then just remove the one you don't want to show and pass in the new NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a UIButton as the UIBarButtonItem's customView. Then set the hidden property on the customView (UIButton)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than deleting the bar button item and destroying the button and it's attached storyboard segue, you can just set it to clear text when it's disabled.

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor clearColor]}
                                                      forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Then when ever you want the bar button item hidden, you can just do:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButton.enabled = NO;
```

It's lame there's no hidden property but this offers the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can just create an IBOutlet reference to the desired UIBarButtonItem and when needed just do as follow:

```
[self.yourOutletRerence setImage: nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution: Just change the BarButtonItem's identifier to custom.